# how to redirect stdin and stdout to a text file in java

Tags: java

How to redirect stdin and stdout to take data as input from a text file and pass data as output to another textfile.

My input and output files look like this.

**Input File.txt**

```
1 2 3
```

The output should be the sum of the numbers in the input file.

**Output File.txt**

```
6
```

Comment: What have you tried yet? Have you tried to read the file, parse it, etc.? If yes, could you provide your code snippets?

Comment: If this is some kind of homework or assignment, please tag the question accordingly, so you get appropriate answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to do that in Java, you can do it from the shell that runs your Java application:

```
# cat input.txt | java -jar myapp.jar > output.txt
```

The Java code can then just read from System.in and write to System.out.

Comment: How would I get a File object then to take a file name from stdin? E.g. `File newFile = new File(???)` when I have `java compiled < afile.txt`?

Comment: There would not be a file there. The contents of `afile.txt` will be piped into `System.in`, you can read from that.

Answer (score 11):

You can set the `System.out` and `System.in` to a file path. Then your existing code should work

```
System.setIn(new FileInputStream(new File("input.txt")));
...
//read from file
.... 

System.setOut(new PrintStream(new File("filename.txt")));
System.out.println(sum); // will be printed to the file
```

Comment: Thanks, I can use your code for practicing and validating my HackerRank testcases.

Answer (score 0):

This is a reflection based solution incorporating part of code from @sidgate's answer:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        runSolution("utopiantree");
    }

    private static void runSolution(String packageName) throws Exception{

        System.setIn(Driver.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(packageName + ".tc"));
        Method mainMethod = Class.forName(packageName + ".Solution").getMethod("main", new Class[]{String[].class});
        mainMethod.setAccessible(true);
        mainMethod.invoke(null, new Object[]{new String[0]});
    }
}
```