# Java: How is reading from a text file using '<' different from other methods?

Tags: java, file, input, command-line-arguments

I usually read from text files passed at the command line using the following method:

```
inFile = new File(args[0]);
```

But I saw somewhere another method that produces similar results:

```
java Main < input.txt
```

However, I could not find anything about the second way.

What is the difference between them?

Comment: Related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886499/how-to-redirect-stdin-and-stdout-to-a-text-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second line is actually not related to java, but is something you can do from the commandline in general.

You can redirect the output of any program (or file), into any other program by using `<`

The code essentially acts as if someone typed all the text in that text file really fast.

You would capture the input by using a `Scanner` or any other way you would normally capture keyboard input